# Is there any way to set spark applicationId format

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit, apache-spark-standalone

I am running spark submit in **standalone** mode, i am getting applicationId in the form of

> app-20231009145337-0067 (app-datetime-number)

but same in spark submit **YARN** mode applicationId is in timestamp format

> application_1695174931058_0190 (application_timestamp_number)

Why there is differance is applicationId generation,
is there any configuration where in standalone mode i can get applicationId same format as yarn mode(with timestamp) ?